# Java Swing - How to make JMenuItem open a new frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jmenu

I am trying to create a program where when the user clicks a JMenuItem (basic) in the frame in class2, it opens the frame in class1. However, when I try to run the code, I keep getting errors about how it can't find the "setVisible" method. I was wondering whether something could give me some pointers. Also, both classes are stored in different java files (but in the same folder).

CLASS 1:

```
public class CalculatorFrame {
    private JFrame frame;
    public String calc = "";
    public CalculatorFrame() {
        frame = new JFrame("Basic Calculator");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

CLASS 2:

```
public class CalculatorFrameA extends CalculatorFrame{
    private JFrame frameA;

    public CalculatorFrameA() {
        frameA = new JFrame("Advanced Calculator");
        frameA.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    ActionListener basicListener = new ActionListener(){ //basic is a JMenuItem
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            CalculatorFrame frame = new CalculatorFrame();
            //frame.show();
            frameA.dispose();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    };
```

Comment: the standard CalculatorFrame does not extend JFrame thats why it cant find setVisible method

Comment: Also, you should probably use a JDialog, not a JFrame

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer it still doesn't work. This time when I click the item, nothing happens.

Comment: `it still doesn't work` - post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. We can't guess what changes you made to he code.